# Should I move my question to math.stackexchange.com?

Tags: discussion, site-recommendation

I just asked https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10272204/hidden-line-removal-without-access-to-opengl on SO, however I don't know if SO is the best place to ask it. The question is more asking how to do the math behind Hidden Line Removal. Also I have a strong suspicion that most people on SO will not have had experience drawing 3D without using a library like OpenGL or Direct3D.

Should I close my question and move it to the mathematics site, <s>open another copy there</s>, or just leave it here as it would not be appropriate there either?

Comment: Removing the "Open another copy option" as I know that should not be done. But I still would like to know, is this question too "mathy" for SO or is it too "Programy" for Math?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't think it would be more appropriate on Math.SE.

Your question is more about the *algorithm*. Honestly, I think it belongs on Programmers.SE. I will flag it for migration. From Programmers.SE FAQ:

> Programmers — Stack Exchange is a site for professional programmers
> who are interested in getting expert answers on conceptual questions
> about software development. If you have a question about…
>
> - algorithm and data structure concepts
>   ...

So algorithmic questions are on topic there. But **do not** rewrite the question yourself. It will me migrated by a moderator.

Comment: Algorithms are on-topic on Stack Overflow too, check the [faq](http://stackoverflow.com/faq#questions). I would expect better answers to algorithm questions on SO than on Prog.SE. But I recommend [cs.se] over both for applied CS questions like this one (assuming the code request is dropped).

Comment: @Gilles There is overlap in that sense. But I'm more Programmers.SE leniant :-)

Answer (score 1):

Your question is definitely not fit for Math, since it is asking for code or pseudo-code, not for mathematical results. If you want code, Stack Overflow is the right place. If you want an algorithm, [Computer Science](https://cs.stackexchange.com/) would be the right place.

I would recommend improving your question (and then, depending on whether you choose to ask for code or for the algorithm, possibly flag to have your question migrated to CS.SE). Have you found a description of Appel's algorithm, or is that part of your problem? What background do you have in computer graphics and computational geometry? A summary of what you've already done in terms of implementing that wire-frame viewer would also help potential answerers know what holes need to be filled in your understanding.